# Adding constraints to 2 labels with multiline in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm having difficulty in adding the constraints to these 2 labels. I want them to be multiline and fit accordingly in the tableview cell. So what constraints should I put?

[image]

Comment: u want both label as multiline label ? And What about width ?

Comment: storyboard or programatically? and what do you mean `fit accordingly`?

Comment: @JoeHuang Storyboard only. And fit accordingly means, if the first label is : "Stackoverflow" and other label is "is cool". So I should get "Stackoverflow is cool". But both the labels have to be multiline.

Comment: if u want 2 sentences show as u explain in above comment  then use only one label and set text after join both sentences

Comment: add 'firs label' left and top constraint to cell content view

Comment: for 'second label' add top and right constraints to cell content view

Comment: do labels have equal widths?

Comment: @engmahsa No equal widths. And I want the 2nd label to start just after the 1st label.

Comment: ok make a horizontal spacing between the labels with 0 value

Answer (score 0):

1.for 'first label' add left and top constraints to Content view of cell with value = 0 ;

2.and also for 'Second label' add right and top constraints to Content view of cell with value = 0 ;

3.create a horizontal spacing between labels.

4.and use UITableViewAutomaticDimension at heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: If I do like this, then the horizontal spacing between the labels becomes around 500 which is not right.

Comment: you can select it and change it to zero

Comment: It doesn't work. Can you try adding a long text on both the labels and check what's the result?

Comment: for both labels add height constraint but doesn't select 'equal value' select 'greater than'